# What is wrong with doctrine2 query builder - expected literal

Tags: doctrine-orm, zend-framework2

I am using Doctrine 2 within ZF2 code and I am trying to write update query.
Code is like this:

```
    $qb = $this->getEntityManager()->createQueryBuilder();
    $qb->update('Application\Entity\Groups', 'group')
            ->set('group.state', '?1')
            ->set('group.modified', '?2')
            ->where($qb->expr()->eq('group.id', '?3'))
            ->setParameter(1, \Application\Entity\Groups::STATE_DELETED)
            ->setParameter(2, $modified)
            ->setParameter(3, $group_id);
```

Doctrine2 complains about query. Exact error message is:
(string) [Syntax Error] line 0, col 87: Error: Expected Literal, got 'group'

Answer (score 1):

It seems that keyword group created problems. When I used gr alias instead of group it worked fine.
So, DQL bellow worked:

```
    $qb = $this->getEntityManager()->createQueryBuilder();
    $qb->update('Application\Entity\Groups', 'gr')
            ->set('gr.state', ':state')
            ->set('gr.modified', ':modified')
            ->where($qb->expr()->eq('gr.id', ':group_id'))
            ->setParameter('group_id', $group_id)
            ->setParameter('state', \Application\Entity\Groups::STATE_DELETED)
            ->setParameter('modified', $modified);
```